# why my hash functions doesnt work or freez in the /sys/kernel/tracing/per_cpu/cpu45 folder?

Tags: linux, bash, md5sum

Im having issue with my script that calulates intergity on this version of ubunutu :

```
cyber@ubuntu:/$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: ubuntu
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 48d13c046d74421781e6c6f771f6ac31
           Boot ID: 847b838897ac47eb932f6427361232d1
    Virtualization: vmware
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.13.0-51-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Im wondering if /sys/kernel/tracing/per_cpu/cpu45 is not by any chance an alive file ?
because calculating the hash of the files inside takes ifinite time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check filesystem integrity, skip the whole `/sys` folder - it is an interface to the kernel.

Also it would be better if you also skip `/proc` (also kernel interface) and `/dev` (special or device files) folders. F.e - you can read from `/dev/zero` or `/dev/urandom` forever. Network mounts can give you a lot of bright moments too.

Also your script can freeze on reading pipes - it there is enough permissions it can read from a pipe forever.

If I was building such a script, I'll start from the mounts, checked their filesystems and scanned only needed ones. For example if a mount is `tmpfs` - it's contents is located in RAM and will be wiped after reboot.

And you totally should check it out -
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: I try to scan as mush files as i can on very different versions on linux systemes. What else should I skip on Ubunutu 20.04 ? Because my scipt seems to be blocked again.

Comment: I've added some examples. Check `mount -l` output for filesystems and their types.

Comment: I understand that `mount -l` will list the files that are not to hash. is that correct ?

Comment: no, it shows mounted filesystems. You have to check their type (for example `sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)` has type `sysfs`, and skip types you don't need to scan. Also, you have to check the file before scanning - it can be a link or a pipe or something else. So you need to be sure that reading of this file will success.